USB3300: ULPI link reports "Failed PLL lock" error upon booting into Petalinux
Currently debugging the USB2.0 transceiver or PHY chip (USB3300) that seem to fail to have the ULPI link lock the transmitted 60MHz clock signal (PLL lock failed error). I found that the chip's crystal to have a low drive level (100uW versus 500uW as demanded in the USB3300 datasheet). But then again, I am able to see the ULPI clk output as 60MHz from the chip every power-up and after power-up with no clear issues. We have 4 SOMs in our lab, and according to our firmware engineer, one out of 4 SOMs is able to achieve 100% PLL lock successfully, the other 3 SOMs constantly fail PLL locking using exactly the same PCB and firmware. The SOM connects to the PCB through Samtec connectors so its easy to swap SOMs.
Now obviously its weird why would one SOM out of 4 achieve PLL locking successfully, when all are brand new bought from Digikeys. The SOM is "Kria24" by AMD which has the Zynq Ultrascale+ MPSoC.
The only hardware issue I can spot is the crystal "Drive level", I have designed my USB3300 circuit with a 100uW drive level crystal instead of 500uW. I plan to order a 500uW radial crystal and mod my board to see if I can finally achieve phase locking successfully to get the ULPI link up and running to use the USB2.0.
But assuming the issue is actually something else, I simply wanted to share with you my crystal and clock signals using the existing 100uW hoping that someone can spot something I couldn't see:
The crystal output (24MHz as demanded by the application):

The USB3300 ULPI clock output as measured from a series termination resistor close the ULPI clock pin:

Interestingly, I enabled the 1.8V internal regulators on the USB3300 chip to match the SOM IO tolerance of 1.8V. I can see the ULPI clk signal oscillating to peaks beyond 1.8V, is this normal? Appreciate if you can shed some light on the potential implications of using 100uW instead of a 500uW drive level crystal, but also your analysis of the captures I shared and how all of this might be connected to failure in phase locking the ULPI 60MHz clock signal.
Thanks.

is VDDIO = 1.8V or 3V?

So there are two VDD1.8 pins available on the chip for the internal 1.8V regulators. and I confirm that I do have the internal regulators on, both of these pins "VDD1.8" and "VDDA1.8" measure 1.8V.

In cases of having little understanding of how a Pierce oscillator works in the particular USB3300 situation, it is advisable to follow manufacturer's design examples to finest details, including the exact type of crystal, load capacitors, and PCB traces.

The 60MHz clock is a digital output. It is supposed to look like a square wave. Something is wrong on the CLKOUT net of your connection to SOM.

Also, since you have a modified XTAL circuit and its negative resistance margins are likely compromised, you need to look at the clock start-up time (from RESET or SUSPEND) state, there are timing limits in USB applications.

The 60 MHz clock appears to exceed the VddIO MAX.  However, you may have some probe ground ESL amplifying the signal yet your mean DC suggests the CLk driver runs at higher voltages.  I suggest you contact OEM support regarding the discrepancy and potential "SCR-effect condition".
Update 2440 yyww
I recall in simulating a discrete RF Xtal that the max Xtal power is based on the fact that in internal motional capacitance in [fF] amplifies the I/O voltage by the Xc ratio for resonant current. This is in kV across a very thin quartz lattice and even with very high kV/mm can breakdown. It is not a thermal issue, rather it is an insulation breakdown suggested limit and is normally regulated by the driver V and series R in the kohm range. If the CMOS gain has enough margin at high temp and low Vdd, I would disregard the SOM rating as a guidance and not a must have limit.  But verifying your current limiting R should be done for Irms*Vrms (diff) is often overlooked.  Newer Xtals may be microslice and thus lower breakdown voltage , BDV rated by uW dissipation.
Bottom line: follow the Xtal specs not the IC. The problem seems to be the PLL VCO sensitivity for reasons unknown.
Your Xtal output looks good. As long as it has an adequate sine amplitude to drive the inverter output you are good. An option to boost Vout is to shift the ratio from equal C’s to higher after the output Rs and with lower on Vin for OSC port with the C|| equiv. tuned to spec. load C.
For avoid these issues in future, choose an XO IC (24MHz) to drive OSC In and shop around for best $ and ppm error.
Regarding the PLL, since the tuning range is wide it must be using a typeII mixer (phase-freq) and my guess is the span of the VCO has a tolerance that permitted 1/4 parts to reach 60 MHz. This will also be sensitive to fail at low Vdd (I believe) for the VCO and high junction temps, so margin testing is essential(Schmoo plots for guys who worked in Silicon Valley during the  late60/70/80+’s) You could verify this hypothesis by raising the supply 10% on a SOM that fails.
Pls update your test results and votes are how the site appreciates pro bono answers.
 [ p11]

p19 above
——————————————-
Historical answer
These are separate issues.
All Fox's SMD 24 MHz Xtals are 0.5mW.  PD max levels always decrease with frequency. e.g. 32kHz 1uW max and may increase with pF load. Adding a series Rs might reduce the gain margin worse.
Normally, CMOS drivers are between 22 and 66 Ohms (Vol/Io=Ro) but the Xtal ESR is in series with its LC series impedance while in parallel resonance.
Not sure about 100 uW levels after Xtal and load C2 but usually adding 10 ohms between C1 and X to measure current is a good method and increasing till failure proves gain margin.
When in doubt, an XO chip is more reliable than an X & load caps, C and often better ppm error.

Thanks for sharing this. I have come to believe that the issue is in the USB controller, particularly the driver "dwc3" side of things instead of the PHY or the PCB layout. Apparently, even though I am not using USB 3.0, the dwc3 driver still scans to phase lock into the USB 3.0 differential clock, which is weird, people report that with this clock signal, they gaurantee good linkage to their USB 2.0 High speed PHY. There has got to be a way to modify the dwc3 driver to function without this clock, because clearly I am not using USB 3.0. I believe the controller is like USB 3.0 and USB 2.0 hub
